# Need recommendations for a system for storing test cases, test results, build details, etc

Tags: test-management, development-process, defect-tracking, source-control

I am working on a process improvement effort, and I need to get our QA operations up to the industry standards.

I am exploring the various systems available in the marketplace which help to store information associated with software development. We currently are using Wrike for defect tracking, but Wrike is task-oriented.

The ideal system I am looking for has these characteristics:

- Allows storing requirements
- Allows storing test cases and allows grouping them into suites and sets
- Allows storing test results on per-build basis; a failed test case should be associated with a defect
- Allows storing defect/issue information
- Allows storing build information
- Has code repository (git is preferred)
- Has a Wiki or a similar system where knowledge can be stored
- Has integrations with other systems and/or has a good API so we can integrate it ourselves

I have already reviewed the following systems:

- qTest by QA Symphony
- GitHub
- GitLab
- Jira/Confluence by Atlassian
- Redmine
- Taiga
- TestLink
- Gitea
- Trac
- RallyDev by CA Agile

They are all interesting systems; some are more suitable than others for our needs. Cost is certainly a factor; an open source system would be of interest, but I am considering commercial systems as well.

**I am looking for additional systems to evaluate.** Any suggestions?

Comment: Tip: This endeavor should be someway shared with the team - Constant sync meetings, POC/experimentation, divide research tasks, etc. The ones who make a product are not the tools, but the people; if the tools don't fit the specific people in the team, they will be, at better, underused.

Comment: For me, additional important criteria for consideration would be the language tool was written in - in case you need to do some customization. This will also narrow your search considerably. I really like Trac, because it has convenient integration between bug tracker, wiki (for documentation, requirements, test cases etc) and code repository/viewer. And is written in Python, easiest to customize.

Comment: In my search for a perfect system, I found some research done by XStudio team:
[http://www.xqual.com/qa/tools.html](http://www.xqual.com/qa/tools.html)
This page lists various tools and shows which aspects of SDLC management it supports.

Comment: Gitlab does the whole job properly now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried many of those tools in several different companies.
I consider my ideal choices to be:

- Jira
- Github
- CircleCI

I've found Jira to be more flexible and as a better UI IMO than Trello, 
 VSTS and Pivotal Tracker that I have used.  Jira also integrates well with Confluence from the same company.
Github and gitflow is the lightest weight code review system I have seen and Github is the most commonly used code storage site.
CircleCI is the most modern Continuous Integration system I have used and I prefer it greatly to Jenkins (probably market leader) and VSTS (Microsoft offering).

A key part to me is that three system **integrate** well with each other.

For example:

When you look at a ticket you can easily click through the code, build and tests for that.  Similarly you can start at the code and with a ticket number navigate 'up' to see its story and feature.

Answer (score 1):

- Bugzilla for issue / bug tracking; [Bugzilla wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugzilla)
- TeamCity for build and deployment; [TeamCity wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamCity)
- Octopus Deploy for automated deployment; really good if you are working with .NET [Octopus Deploy wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octopus_Deploy)
- QAComplete for issue / bug tracking; the best choice if you are using SopaUI or test complete. [TestComplete link](https://smartbear.com/product/qacomplete/overview/)
- Trello for task management, [Trello wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trello)